# Why do DNS tools report glue record problems even though they look right?

Tags: domain-name-system, glue-record

I've been bashing my head to a bloody pulp trying to figure this out. I have my custom nameservers setup at my registrar. I have the nameservers assigned to the domain. The nameservers have the appropriate A and NS records. Manual lookup tests return proper results. The world seems able to find my website and send me email. Yet DNS validity tests tell me the glue records don't match between "local" and "parent". What am I missing?!?!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First - using the right tool makes a world of difference. I stumbled onto this site and it's an absolute godsend: [ViewDNS.info](https://viewdns.info/dnsreport/)

Run your domain with this tool - and instead of just getting red & yellow messages with demands to sign up and pay for monitoring - you'll get actual information you can use to fix problems. Of course, you still have to **read** for this information to help.

In my case, after comparing the results of, "NS records listed at parent servers" against the, "NS records at your local servers" - I still didn't see the problem. The IP's were identical. Identical. $#@!ing identical!!!

Then I kept comparing - and realized the TTL's were different. I had a short TTL defined on my records because I wanted changes to propagate faster. But at least some DNS records shouldn't change that fast. I personally think it's...!@#$ing stupid that the TTL is being tested and that most tools don't tell you that's what the problem is.

Anyway - hopefully this helps someone else. And many thanks to the Australian company providing this wonderful tool - I never would have figured this out without it.

Comment: Requiring TTLs to match between zone and glue records seems... really odd, to be honest. I don't think I've _ever_ seen such a thing in DNS "test" tools.